# SonataAdminBundle + styles don't show properly

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

Any idea why my admin area shows like this:

[image]

I installed assets with no problem.
and here is my config.ylm file:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm 
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\User

    group:
        group_class:   Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager

sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:  # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.user.block.menu:         # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account:      # used to display menu option (login option)
        sonata.block.service.text: # used to if you plan to use Sonata user routes
```

Comment: Same Problem, looks like sonata-core does not update to the latest version when running composer update.

Comment: Thanks to gentleman at Sonata repo here is the reply that I've received.I hope it helps others:
Some assets in dev-master branch were moved from SonataAdminBundle to SonataCoreBundle. 
I recommend you to use the stable branch ~2.3, dev-master is a work in progress.
If you want to try dev-master the assets should work. Please make sure, you've cleared the cache, installed assets with app/console assets:install command and have configurade the assets:stylesheets in your config.yml correctly (same paths as the default SonataAdmin have) or do not configure it to let use the defulat stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

They have moved dependencies from SonataAdminBundle to SonataCoreBundle (look at [this](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/issues/104) issue in github).

In my case I was missing completely explicit require of sonata-core in composer.json.